# How to find the byte length of a string

Tags: string, dart

I want to get the number of bytes in an arbitrary string. I can do it this way:

```
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  String str = '你好';
  final bytes = utf8.encode(str);
  print(str.length);    // 2
  print(bytes.length);  // 6
}
```

But is there a more direct way to do it that doesn't involve doing a conversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no **one** byte <--> String mapping. You have to pick an encoding to figure out the number of bytes. UTF-8 is the most common.